# Pure CSS Accordion Issue

Tags: css, accordion

I'm playing around with a pure CSS accordion http://reversl.net/accordion/ I can get the basic functionality to work (headings 2 & 3 both toggle) But I can't get heading 1 to toggle if I add the same UL to it. Because Heading 1 is styled differently the problem (I think) lies within naming/targeting it's + div ?

*Please note: I removed the UL from Heading 1 for the sake of the demo because it was preventing Headings 2 & 3 from toggling.*

Comment: Data belongs in HTML, it's the Model; Styles belong in CSS, it's the View; Interactions belong in JavaScript, it's the controller.

Comment: @zzzzBov Visibility changes should not regard as interaction. If you could do it with CSS3 and your audience supports it, fine!

Comment: @Jedda I like the `:target` part. Didn't know about that. How's is browser compatibility with that? http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-target

Comment: @yunzen, Visibility changes are most definitely interaction, however the way in which they occur can be managed by CSS3. The actual change in visibility should happen via JS adding/removing classes and other attributes (such as [`[aria-hidden]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden))

Comment: @yunzen seems to be supported by ie9 +, FF10.0.2+, Saf 5.1+, Chrome 17+ and Opera 11.6+

Comment: @zzzzBov If you change the CSS classes with JS, then the visibility change is done by CSS not by JS. As you said JS is the controller. But the browser is a controller, too. And Jedda uses the browser as controller by using `:target` CSS pseudo class

Comment: @yunzen, the cause of the state change (changing of the class) should be left to JavaScript, using `:target` in CSS to cause a visibility change goes against the MVC nature of HTML, CSS, and JS. You're right in that CSS should be used to make the elements invisible, but this should be triggered by JS.

Comment: @zzzzBov Havin ONLY JavaScript as MVC Controller seems a little harsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made several mistakes. Too many to count:

Here is a working example: Try and see, what I changed
http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/ASqE9/

### HTML

```
<div id="wrap">

<div class="accordion">

    <div id="two" class="section">
        <h4>
            <a href="#two">Heading 2</a>
        </h4>
        <div class="sub_section">
            <ul class="list">
                <li>Sample Text 1</li>
                <li class="last">Sample Text 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </div><!--#two-->

    <div id="four" class="section progress">
        <h4>
            <a href="#four">Heading 4 (With Progress Bar)</a>
        </h4>
        <div class="metrics">
            <div class="meter">
                <span style="width: 75%"></span>
            </div><!--.meter-->
        </div><!--.metrics-->
        <div class="sub_section">
            <ul class="list">
                <li>Sample Text 1</li>
                <li class="last">Sample Text 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--.sub_section-->
    </div><!--#one-->


</div><!--accordian-->
</div>​
```

---

### CSS

```
  #wrap {
      width: 320px;
      background: #f0f0f0;
      margin: auto;
  }

  .accordion {
      clear: both;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .accordion h4 {
      margin: 0;
  }

  .accordion h4 a {
      padding: 1em;
      color: #999;
      display: block;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  .accordion h4 a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      background: #111;
  }

  .accordion .section {
      background: #222;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  }

  .accordion .sub_section {
       border-bottom: none;
       background: #f0f0f0;
  }

  .list {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
  }

  .list li {
      background: url('http://www.placehold.it/40x40') no-repeat;
      color: #999;
      list-style: none;
      padding: .7em .7em .7em 4em;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  }

  .list .last {
      border-bottom: none;
  }

  .accordion .sub_section {
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
      -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
      -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
      transition: height 0.3s ease-in;
  }

    .accordion :target h4 a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
  }

  .accordion :target .sub_section {
      height: 80px;
  }

  .accordion .section.large:target h4 + div {
      overflow: auto;
  }

  .accordion p {
      color: #646464;
  }

  .accordion .progress .meter {
     width: 90%;
     height: 2px;
     position: relative;
     background: #555;
     margin: -.9em auto .5em auto;
     padding: 1px;
  }

  .meter > span {
      height: 2px;
      display: block;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
  }



  ​
```

Comment: Wow your right! Quite a few mistakes for sure :-/ Some of note are: in the HTML you removed the heading from the .metrics div. You also removed the div id "two" from the sub-section (why was this?) In the CSS you fixed some of the selectors that I had muddled right? Did I miss anything?

Comment: @Jedda I removed the ids from the sub_section, because you shall not have two same ids. I removed the heading from the metrics, becuase you defined to show the divs AFTER the heading.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One thing I'm a little confused on though! Why use Div id="two" and Div id="four" etc rather than Div id="three"?

Comment: I could name it back to one and two, but I was too lazy. Use foo, bar and baz instead, those have no meaning

Comment: I Gotcha. Cheers for the help

Comment: This will work in IE8, too. With a little help from JavaScript http://jsfiddle.net/ASqE9/14/

Answer (score 1):

This is because the class "progress" assigned to the div id="one" that keeps constant the size of the div with the content.